# Latex beamer: spacing in header

Tags: beamer, spacing, header-footer, setspace

When using \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} the extra spacing is on the entire slide, also in the header. Before an update there was no extra space in the headder. Does anybody know how to avoid extra spacing in header when using \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}, otherwise I have to modify all my slides.
In the mini example the spacing in the header is that large that the one section (Section 5) is partly out of the visible range. 
Do you know any alternative to \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}?

Mini example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}    
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\begin{document}  
    \section{Section 1} 
    \section{Section 2}
    \section{Section 3}
    \section{Section 4} 
    \section{Section 5}
    \subsection{Sub 1}
    \frame{\frametitle{\textbf{title}} 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text                      
        \item text
        \end{itemize}}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot use `setspace` with `beamer`, it reports `\@ptsize` control sequence undefined error. Hence I manually change the line spacing.

The key is to reset line spacing in beamer templates `headline` and `frametitle`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{split}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\linespread{1.0}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\linespread{1.0}\selectfont}

\linespread{1.25} % manual set one-half spacing

\begin{document}  
\section{Section 1} 
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4} 
\section{Section 5}
\subsection{Sub 1}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  text
  \begin{itemize}
      \item text
      \item text
      \item text
      \item text                      
      \item text
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: normal line spacing in headline and frametitle]